# For fixed $A$, which matrices $B$ make $BA$ stable?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, control-theory, least-squares

Given a fixed $m\times n$ matrix $A$ over reals, which $n\times m$ real-valued matrices $B$ guarantee that $BA$ is stable, ie all eigenvalues have negative real part?

Motivation: any such matrix should correspond to a convergent iterative method for solving a consistent system of linear equations $Ax=b$: pick small-enough $\mu>0$ and arbitrary $x$ and iterate $x = x+\mu B(Ax-b)$ until convergence.

- $B=-A^\dagger$ gives Newton's method
- $B=-A^T$ is batched [LMS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter)
- $B=-I$ is Richardson iteration (convergent when $A\succ 0$)

Comment: By an argument parallel to the one I used in my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4485714) to your other question, we see that $BA$ is stable if and only if $B=SA^++Z^T$ for some stable $n\times n$ matrix $S$ and some $m\times n$ matrix $Z$ such that $Z^TA=0$. If you pick a matrix $\widehat{A}$ with $m-n$ columns such that its column space is the orthogonal complement of the column space of $A$, you may express $Z^T$ as $W\widehat{A}^T$ where $W\in\mathbb R^{n\times(m-n)}$ is arbitrary.

Comment: In order for $B\,A$ to be a stable/Hurwitz matrix requires at least that $B\,A$ is non-singular. So am I correct to assume that $m \geq n$ and that $A$ is full rank?